# Use a text box as a wildcard search on a field within a linked SQL Server Table within MS Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I've managed to successfully build a combo-box that will allow a user to select a record from a list to get an ID from a table. With the table I'm currently working with running to around 60,000 records, it's not realistic to use this method to find the record.

What I want the user to be able to do is enter a name in a text box, and a combo box be populated with the relevant records from the table where one of the fields matches that. So if the user entered 'This' into the text box, the combo box would present records where the field had 'This', 'This and That' and 'this'. It would not present the record that only had 'That' in the field.

Lets say the Text box is called 'txtBox', the combo-box is called 'comBox' and the field in the linked SQL Server table 'LinkedTable' is called 'SearchField'

Comment: First you have to decide what triggers the update of the combo box. Text box events are tricky because you have to decide if you do the update on every keystroke or if you wait for the user to finish typing and tab out. Then read the text and create the row source for the combo box (that is just an Access SQL query). Feed it to the combo box and requery it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down a different route to the suggested option in the other answer. This met my needs more accurately and might help someone with a similar issue.

First, I amended the query on the Combo box so that it used the value in the text box as a criteria for one of the fields.

In the Criteria for the 'SearchField' within 'LinkedTable' I entered:

```
Like "*" & [forms]![*FormName*]![txtBox] & "*"
```

This will restrict the results in comBox to those where the SearchField contains the value entered into txtBox. This doesn't update dynamically however and will only update after the first value entered into txtBox.

To get around this problem, I added the following to the 'On Get Focus' event for comBox

```
Private Sub comBox_GotFocus()

    Dim ctlCombo As Control

    ' Return Control object pointing to a combo box.
    Set ctlCombo = Forms!FormName!comBox

    ' Requery source of data for list box.
    ctlCombo.Requery

End Sub
```

This will force the combo box to run the query again, using the current value in txtBox, each time it is 'clicked on'

As a result, I get the restricted list of values in the combo box that I need and allows the user to 'search' for a record that can then be used for creating a new record on a form.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not use the combo box. Just have a text box in which the user can type in a few characters and hit enter key.

You THEN display a “list” of results that allows the user to select and click on any of the results to “edit” or “view” the given row of data.

In the following screen shot we working with a VERY small table of 500,000 rows. We looking for smith, so we just type in smi and hit enter. The results are displayed instant, and at that point the user can type in “first name” or just a few chars of first name and further drill down and filter.

The form looks like this:

[image]
The code in the after update event of the text box is simply:

```
Dim strSQL    as String

strSQL = "select * from tblCustomers where LastName like '" & me.TextSearch & "*’"
me.RecordSource = strSQL
```

So very little code is required. You could I suppose fill in the results to a combo box, but then the user has to type into a box, then select something from a combo box and then somehow you bring up that record for editing. That’s like 3+ steps for the user.

Just use what Google or most accounting or darn near any computer software does:

A simple text box – you type in a few characters and when they hit enter the results are displayed for the user to pick.

Note in above the user can click on the “glasses” icon button to launch a form that displays the single record. The code behind that button is:

```
Docmd.Openform "frmEditDetails",,,"ID = " & ME!ID
```